# How to import a gradle project into Intellij without it creating .iml files

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I have a 'pure' gradle project containing build.gradle, settings.gradle and a src folder. Nothing else.

I want to open this in IntelliJ but I don't want IntelliJ to add its own module files. I want the project to remain 'pure' gradle so that it can be built and run from the commandline later. I have managed to do this properly with other projects, but with the current project I'm trying to import/open, every time I open it, IntelliJ creates a Project.iml file.

I'm sure I can live with the .iml file being there, but I don't want it, and I'd like to understand what is going on.

I have "Delegate IDE build/run actions to gradle" switched on in preferences. I have tried to both "Import" and "Open" the project from IntelliJ's wizard. I have removed the .idea folder each time I try this. I've tried different setting in the Import/Open wizards. IntelliJ always creates the .iml. Worse, if I try to remove that file it screws up the view of the project structure in the Project pane.

Comment: What makes you think the commands line Gradle cares about iml files?

Comment: Upon further inspection, my other projects do have .iml files but they live inside the .idea folder, meaning that at least they don't bother me. I can live with this, but I'd like to understand how one works with the philosophy of using IDEA with pure gradle projects.

Comment: @cricket_007 I don't think that. I just don't want the iml file in my project. Call me pedantic.

Comment: All JetBrains projects create these files when you open a **project**. You don't need a project to just use your IDE as a text editor

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007, but if I have "Delegate IDE build/run actions to gradle" set, what is the purpose of the iml file? I would imagine it is redundant, as whatever it describes is already served by your gradle build file.

Comment: No, not redundant. it tells the IDE about the project setup. For example, in Intellij Ultimate , you can define a Database connection to browse within the IDE. It also stores your dictionary file for typo correct within the project scope. Gradle is purely for your code and running it. Not configuring your project space

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 6):

When importing a Gradle `build.gradle` file in IntelliJ IDEA there is a setting called **Store generated project files externally**:

[image: ext]

If you enable it, you will not have to [exclude IntelliJ IDEA generated project files from the version control](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544839). Generated files will be stored under [idea.system.path](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519) instead.

Comment: Fantastic. I'll try that.